# Beginner event handling: Any tips to cleaning up/shortening similar functions using OOP and without?

Tags: python, matplotlib, oop

Beginning Python coder here. I know the saying "functions *do* things, classes *are* things", but I think I'm getting my head tied in a knot here. Given that there I have four functions, my head immediately steers towards using OOP. But if I don't *have* to use OOP, how would I go about cleaning these up without it if they are tied to on_click events?

```
def reset_all(event):
    slider_one.reset()
    slider_two.reset()
    slider_three.reset()
    print('All sliders reset.')

def reset_one(event):
    slider_one.reset()
    print('Slider 1 reset\n')

def reset_two(event):
    slider_two.reset()
    print('Slider 2 reset\n')

def reset_three(event):
    slider_three.reset()
    print('Slider 3 reset\n')

button_allreset.on_clicked(reset_all)
button_onereset.on_clicked(reset_one)
button_tworeset.on_clicked(reset_two)
button_threereset.on_clicked(reset_three)
```

Would appreciate any/all examples using OOP and without :-)

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the easiest way is using arrays, and function closure:

```py
sliders = [slider_one, slider_two, slider_three]
def reset_all(event):
    for slider in sliders:
        slider.reset()
    print('All sliders reset.')

def reset(n):
    def f(event):
        sliders[n-1].reset()
        print(f'Slider {n} reset\n')

button_allreset.on_clicked(reset_all)
button_onereset.on_clicked(reset(1))
button_tworeset.on_clicked(reset(2))
button_threereset.on_clicked(reset(3))
```

Otherwise, I see no problem on agrupate related functionalities in a class, although does not represents a "thing".